# Is it a good practice to commit to HEAD?

Tags: version-control, cvs, cvsnt

I've been working on an enterprise application for a few months now, and noticed that the latest "stable" code was committed from a branch to HEAD instead of being tagged as a version.

I have always thought that code must be committed to a branch during the development process, and then sealed/tagged in version when reaching some kind of milestone (end of sprint in a scrum project, code ready for production use, etc.).

What's the standard practice used in the software development industry?